# Delete records From table based on certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns:

```
NAME, MOBILE, CITY
```

It does not have any unique column.

While dumping data from excel the fields haven't been be mapped correctly, as a result mobile numbers have been dumped into CITY column.
Now i have to clean those, there are some 10 million records.

The CITY column consists of both city data and mobile data.

Any Idea on how do i clean up?

Comment: `DELETE FROM table` and import again?

Comment: there are thousands of excel sheets to import data, it may take more than a month. and also all the excels are in different format, so anything i have to do is only in DB.

Comment: Is the mobile field empty on the rows where this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume all cities start with a letter, and everything that doesn't is a telephone number. Then you could do the following

```
DELETE FROM table
  WHERE LEFT(city, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'
    AND LEFT(city, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
```

Comment: All cities start with alphabets, I need to delete those records from Table where CITY column doesnt start with Alphabet.

Comment: Thank you  Glorfindel . From next time when i post i will see that it is in formatted way as u have done now.Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. It wasn't my edit, however (though I did approve it through the review system).